# sync calendar and contacts without iCloud in Mavericks

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, contacts, calendar

How can I sync calender and contacts in Mavericks and iOS 7 without using iCloud (or any cloud for that matter)? Is the only option really to setup a CalDav and CardDav server in my local home WiFi network? If so, how do I do it? Will I be needing a dedicated machine for the server (I just have one iMac)? Will all my devices automatically be able to sync once they are connected to the local WiFi? Do you know of any good step by step tutorial?

Comment: Why the downvote? Too many questions at once?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm wondering if http://owncloud.org could do the trick?

Comment: SyncServices is no more in Mavericks.

Comment: Local sync was eliminated from Mavericks. A major annoyance, and a transparent move to force users into iCloud.

Comment: It was not transparent to me at all. Apple did never mention publicly that this feature is gone.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a small open source app for [iOS](https://github.com/yep/iosCalSync) and [OS X](https://github.com/yep/osxCalSync) to do basic calendar synchronization over USB on Mavericks. The iOS app has been submitted to the AppStore and is currently waiting for review.

---

**Update**:

I had to rename the app to get accepted, but it is in the iOS AppStore now:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/devicesync-for-ios/id737867459?mt=8

Please read the AppStore app description before using it!

You have to get the corresponding OS X app from [here](https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-OS-X/releases)
(Hold ctrl key while double click to open and to get past the "unregistered developer" error).

See [DeviceSync-for-OS-X](https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-OS-X) and [DeviceSync-for-iOS](https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-iOS) at github.

This app is open source and hence a collaborative effort. If you are a developer or know some iOS developers, feel free to add missing functionality (send a pull request at github).

Comment: It can't do contacts synch too, can it?

Comment: @bitbonk: not yet, working on it

Answer (score 4):

The next version if iTunes is supposed do bring back offline/local calendar and contact  synching without iCloud. iTunes 11.1.6 is currently in beta and already contains this feature.

http://www.macrumors.com/2014/03/18/itunes-beta-local-syncing/

Answer (score 0):

@bitbonk, I'm syncing Contacts without iCloud via USB on iOS7.0.4 / Mavericks. At first I didn't think it was working (which is how I found this thread) but after looking under "Groups" from within the Contacts app I saw that, for some reason, only one Group was selected. (Evidently this got switched during a recent upgrade. I'm still not sure.) After choosing All Groups and syncing, all my contacts are now showing up again!

I am, however, having to use iCloud for Calendar syncing.

Comment: Does it say "ICLOUD" above the list of groups in you iOS contacts app?

Answer (score 0):

There is a company which claims ( and we all know what the word
"claims" can mean in the software world ) to be working on a 
complete sync utility which will work without iCloud.

Here is a link to that company ( with which I have no affiliation).

http://blog.eltima.com/2013/11/syncmate-5-is-coming-this-winter.html

There is some info on the product they claim will be released soon
which will enable local sync of iOS devices. I for one hope they
come through with this software, because by choice I will never use iCloud or any other cloud service for my private data; I know too much about what can happen when there is a data breach and my data stays
on my personal hardware, period.

I DO suggest that all who are unhappy about the removal of local sync
in Mavericks let Mr. Tim Cook know how they feel about it. I wrote 
him and he never replied, which I did not find encouraging unless 
perhaps Mr. Cook wants me to quit buying Apple products, in which 
case his refusal to reply was VERY encouraging.

His email address is :

tcook@apple.com

Comment: I wouldn't expect writing the CEO of any company to be a good way to get a response or change the course of that company. Of course some emails get filtered / seen / addressed, but to each their own I suppose.

Comment: YES! The [free edition](http://sync-mac.com/syncmate-expert.html) of SyncMate **does sync** contacts and calendars without hassle. Much appreciated, thanks!